# Dynamically set the source of the autocomplete and then dynamically run it

Tags: php, jquery, html, input, autocomplete

I have input:text field where I search names with ajax help to connect to database. On each key-up it does this:
1) ajax finds from database all the results that were similar to the input value;
2) stores all results into array;
3) dynamically updates the input autocomplete source with an array that was made in step 2);

and now I wan't to make the 4th step: dynamically tell autocomplete to run the text that were written in the input field to show all actual results.

The problem now is that autocomplete shows results that were one key-up behind. For example:
if I write word "Tommy", then autocomplete will show me the results for "Tomm" because the autocomplete was faster than it's source update in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer by myself:

```
$("#YourInputId").autocomplete("search", $("#YourInputId").val());
```

Didn't know about the "search" attribute for autocomplete method.